# Angular2 reactive forms select multiple attribute?

Tags: forms, angular, select, reactive

I use the following code in my app with reactive forms.

If I uncomment the `[multiple]` line, the **Choose ...** option does not set the `dformControl` form control object back to status `INVALID`.

`dformControl.multiple` by the way returns `false`. Even if I change the commented line to `[multiple]="false"`, still switching back to the **Choose ...** option does NOT set the form control status to `INVALID`.

```
<select class="form-control"
        [id]="dformControl.key"
        [formControlName]="dformControl.key"
        /*[multiple]="dformControl.multiple"*/>

  <option *ngIf="!dformControl.value"
          value="">
    Choose ...
  </option>

  <option *ngFor="let opt of dformControl.options"
          [value]="opt.value"
          [selected]="dformControl.value == opt.value">
    {{opt.label}}
  </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind to the `multiple` property at the select level to a boolean isMultiple. Then you can change it and the select will change as well. Take a look at the this, I change it using a button. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vwRZiKqpaotJyWpQrZcC?p=preview)

```
  <select formControlName="cars" [multiple]="isMultiple">
      <option></option>
      <option *ngFor="let car of cars" >{{car}}</option>
  </select>
```

It seems when adding the multiple property it is affecting the required validator. I was able to just add an extra validator and it worked as expected.

```
Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('.+')]
```

Comment: you got a solution for this one?

Comment: in case `dformControl.multiple` returns `true` it should be a multiple select, in case it returns `false` ist should be a normal select.

Comment: so in your plunkr go choose a value WITHOUT switching to multiple. After that select the empty option again ... form's still valid ... and thats the problem I tried to describe above

Comment: @MaxSolid I added new plunkr