# Angular validator to check if array

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have input with multiselect choise. I want to validate that something is choosen. In normall case I use

```
Validators.required (builder: [[], Validators.required])
```

but regarding to documentations this method works like that:

```
this._required = value != null && value !== false && `${value}` !== 'false';
```

[link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts), so this always return that this filed is filled, becuase I have got here array.

Do You have an idea how to check it using Validators.pattern or do it in another way?
This is my hmtl file:

```
<ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'multiselect'">
<div class="selector-holder overflowable" [ngStyle]="{'z-index': 50 - zIndex}" [ngClass]="{'has-errors': hasErrors(editForm.get(i).get(element)), 'disabled': editForm.get(i).get(element).disabled}">
        <ng-select [allowClear]="false" [multiple]="true"
                [disabled]="editForm.get(i).get(element).disabled"
                    [items]="formDefinition[i].fields[element].options"
                    [active]="getMultiValues(editForm.get(i).get(element))"
                    (selected)="setSelected(editForm.get(i).get(element), $event)"
                    (removed)="setRemoved(editForm.get(i).get(element), $event)"
                    placeholder="{{'select' | translate}}">
            </ng-select>
            <app-form-field-error [control]="editForm.get(i).get(element)"></app-form-field-error>
    </div>
```

And this is my ts file:

```
type type: 'multiselect',
                builder: [[], Validators.required],
                options: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        text: _('Text 1')
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        text: _('Text 2')
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        text: _('Text 3')
                    },
```

And in this case when nothing is selected, I have not got error, but I want to have.

Comment: I hardly belive that validator is the culprit here.

Comment: How are you getting an array into a form field?

Comment: @cale_b I add my html and ts files. Please check now

Comment: Did you see this post? Does it address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080543/870729

Comment: @cale_b I saw, but it is not working. The same situation is when I tried this: [''], Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('.+')]) and capabilities of this and this is not working.